# Excel 365, pivot table and slicer change date format

Tags: excel, date, pivot-table

My employer recently rolled out the new version of Excel to us and by some reason all dates have changed from "YYYY-MM-DD" format to "DD-MMM" format.
It might sound as a small issue but it also means the slicer is now showing the dates sorted by day number, example:

```
Ascending 
1 jan
1 feb
2 jan
2 feb
```

As you can understand that is not a practival way to choose dates in a slicer.
I can change from ascending to decending but that just means the higher day numbers come first.

I can't find any settings for this.
If I look at the clock in the lower right corner it shows YYYY-MM-DD so it's not the regional settings. I also doubble checked it with the control panel settings in windows.

What can I do to change this to YYYY-MM-DD?

[image]

---

### EDIT:

I have tried to change the format of the date but it make no difference.
I also tried to set a custom format but it doesn't make any difference.
[image]

---

### EDIT2:

I tried to create a new pivot table and i get the following as default:
[image]

The months are added automatically when I add dates in the pivot table.
With or without the months there I still can't change the format.

### Edit3:

I have uploaded a copy of a part of the file if anyone wants to try themselves.
It doesn't have all the columns, but it has all the rows that I have at this moment.

http://hoppvader.nu/Pics/date_format.xlsx

Comment: In your original data table, what does a formula like `=ISTEXT(A3)`  ??`=ÄRTEXT(A3)` ?? return?  If it returns `TRUE` for that or any item in the `Datum` column, things may get flakey.   Also, have you tried recreating the Pivot Table since the transition, perhaps in a new workbook?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld that returns false. If I use `=YEAR(A3)` it returns the year so it should be a date field. I will try to redo all the pivot tables tomorrow. Time to go now.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have tried it now and added to the question. But it does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem.
It may not suit everyone but it worked for me.

Remove the "date" formatting of the column in the original data table and make the dates text.

Select the column with the date.
Go to Data -> text to columns and click past the first two steps.
On the third step make the column text.
[image]
This will make all current data text, but you still need to change the format of the column to text to make new data be entered as text.

When that is done the pivot table will show the dates as text, meaning the same way it's presented in the original data table.

The caveat of this is that you can't change the format using the cell formatting options.
Also splitting up months and such is not possible, if you need that done then you need to add a helper column with the month name/number.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the Number format of the date using the pivot-table field items window. Screenshot below

[image: Date format]

Clicking on Number Format(3) will take you to the formatting window where can choose various formats or customize your own.

[image: Number format]

Comment: If you date cell formatted as date? Pivot table won't consider it a date of the main cell format is a Text

Comment: Yes they are all dates. But as I said this all started when I got Excel 365 installed. https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3yNb.png

Comment: Can you also add a screenshot of your main data too? maybe I can find an answer based on that

Comment: Yes Thank you. I've tried using a similar data. It seems to be working for me. I guess this is some issue w.r.t to the transition like you mentioned.

Comment: Just wanted to tell you I found a "solution". It's a dirty hack to circumvent a possible bug in Excel, but it's OK for me. Thanks again for your efforts in this.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File-->Options-->Data and select the option to disable automatic grouping of Date/Time columns in Pivot tables.

You may or may not have to recreate the table.

[image]

Comment: It only did what it was supposed to do, remove the "month" from the table. I still can't change the date format. EDIT, I just noticed it works now on the file I made as a sample. I will try to restart Excel

Comment: Nope.. didn't help. I'm about to go crazy on this now. I can easily change the date format in the original data for as you can see here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijtQr.png But in the pivot table it's stuck. In the example file which is just a copy of my file it works now. But not in the original file...

Comment: @Andreas Before I made that change on your file, the slicer behaved problematically as you demonstrated.  After I made the change, and generated a new pivot table, the slicer behaved as desired.

Comment: Hmm.. didn't even try the slicer this time. Let me check. I can live with the table being wrong but the slicer is more problematic.

Comment: Nope... It's even worse than before. It's showing all dates. And I mean dates. It displays 02-dec. I don't have any data from that date. And I tried to untik the "display data from deleted fields" or whatever it's called in english version of Excel. I believe I have to give up on this....

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you further.  The fix works on the file you uploaded, but must be something else going on with the actual work file.  And I did set my regional settings to Swedish when checking things.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. There is no difference in the column A between the original file and the copy. The only difference is there are columns up to AE, five more sheets and a vba code that downloads the data from web every 10 minutes. This has really puzzled me.

Comment: @Andreas I notice that, on your uploaded workbook, with the Disable option selected, the dates in the "rows" area are real dates that can be formatted, and the slicer shows only the dates that are present in the column (in whatever way that pivot column is formatted).

Comment: Just wanted to tell you I found a "solution". It's a dirty hack to circumvent a possible bug in Excel, but it's OK for me. Thanks again for your efforts in this.